# Check if a cell has null values using regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

The objective is to filter out data which matches a regex in column B while column A is null.

```
df = pd.read_csv('DATA.csv',sep=',',error_bad_lines=False)
fd = df[(df['B'].str.match('.*color\:*') | 
df['B'].str.match('colorful\:*')) & df.A.str.match('^\s*$')]
```

The output obtained using this matches all instances of the word 'color' in column B instead of exact matching 'color:' or 'colorful:'. Also, this code works on rows of column B where corresponding values in column A are non null instead of only running on rows where column A values are null.

Comment: What do you mean by being _null_?

Comment: There are no values in that cell. It's empty

Comment: How do you manage to get _empty_ DataFrame cells from the `read_csv`?

Comment: DATA.csv has two columns A and B. In column A some cells are empty as in 'NaN'. Need to identify these empty cells using a regex

Comment: tried using str.match('^\s*$') to match these empty cells..but it is not matching

Comment: Since _it is not matching_, how can it be that _this code works on all rows of column B_?

Comment: In the output file, all those rows(78 out of 5001 rows) which matched 'color' or 'colorful' (the regex pattern) in column B were available. However these same rows had non null values present in column A...am assuming this means df.A.str.match('^\s*$') was not read at all

Comment: Now you write _these same rows had *non* null values present in column A_, above you wrote _this code works on all rows of column B_, which includes rows with _null values_. Isn't this contradictory?

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways:
first one would be using the .isnull() method:

```
df.A.isnull()
```

second would be:

```
df.A.fillna('').str.contains('^$')
```

however, the regex aproach (second one) isn't optimal

Comment: df.A.isnull()->this omitted the null values..thanks a lot